# Ignoring invalid data from file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that reads in a list of integers from a file, and adds them all together and displays to the user. I can get this program to work properly but what I want to do is have it so if there is an invalid entry in the file (say, a word or anything that isn't a number) it will alert the user and ignore the invalid data and skip to the next available number. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class IntegerReadIn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;

        try {

            File myFile = new File("IntegerReadIn.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                sum = sum + scan.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Total = " + sum);
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No such file name");
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid entry found - integers only.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what error or what problem are you facing?

Comment: What does your file look like? `Scanner.nextInt` would read up until the first `\n` or non `int` character and then `hasNextInt` would be false. Can you give an example of your file?

Comment: Move the `try { ... } catch (InputMismatchException e) { ... }` *inside* your loop.

Comment: @5gon12eder And what should that change? The `while` loop will be left if there is no valid integer to read.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Well, a small test shows me, that `nextInt` doesn't care about `\n` and will read numbers beyond that character.

Answer (score 0):

First use **nextLine()** to read the entire line. after that Use **Integer.parseInt()** method to validate the integer input.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
String s = scan.nextLine();

try{
    Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Error....");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using your while for only `hasNextInt()` you should loop for `haxNext()`

That way you can explicitly check if you get an integer or not (and thus you can provide feedback to the user)

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
   if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
       sum = sum + scan.nextInt();
   } else {
       System.out.println("Invalid Entry: " + scan.next());
   }
}
```

Having this in consideration you will not be needing the `InputMismatchException`